# Python, how to call 2 functions from the same Event

Tags: python, function, class, events, tkinter

Good evening all,

I have an event, Button1, bound to an image to make it clickable. Once it has been clicked it goes to a function. However, i need the Event to go to 2 different function at the same time. The Event works with  1 function at a time (both work but not together) so i presume i am just formatting the Event wrong.

```
self.img_list[2].bind('<Button-1>', removewidgetsHome)
```

I have tried:

```
self.img_list[2].bind('<Button-1>', removewidgetsHome, feedbackpage)
```

But to no avail.

For those who are interested [here is my full code](http://pastebin.com/8bAV2qrX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or for a one liner you could try:

```
self.img_list[2].bind('', lambda *args: (remove_widgets_home(*args), feedback_page(*args))
```

Comment: I feel this is going to be the best option for my code. Thanks so much guys.

Comment: Have in mind that this actually creates a tuple of the return values of the functions so this is not a lisp-style function where you get the 'return value' of the last function called, but it should work since you are only interested in the side effects of the functions.

Answer (score 5):

You could perhaps make a third function that calls the other two rather then trying to figure out how to bind multiple functions:

```
def combined(*args, **kwargs):
    remove_widgets_home(*args, **kwargs)
    feedback_page(*args, **kwargs)

# ...snip...

self.img_list[2].bind('<Button-1>', combined)
```